# Display function output within an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I am trying to output the SELECTED TEXT within my javascript code. I created a function that will get the selected text and I just want to output it when the submit button was output.

Here's the javascript for getting the selected HTML or TEXT.

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
   document.write(html);

}
```

Here's my code for outputting the other content plus the function above (but it wont just show up)

```
(function() 
{
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('my_mce_button', function( editor, url ) 
    {
        editor.addButton( 'my_mce_button', 
        {
            icon: false,
            text: 'Tooltip',
            onclick: function() 
            {
                editor.windowManager.open( 
                {
                    title: 'Tooltip Option',
                    body: 
                    [
                        {
                            type: 'textbox',
                            name: 'textboxtooltipName',
                            label: 'Tooltip Text',
                            value: ''
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'listbox',
                            name: 'listboxClassName',
                            label: 'Class',
                            'values': 
                            [
                                {text: 'Top Tooltip', value: 'top_tooltip'},
                                {text: 'Left Tooltip', value: 'left_tooltip'},
                                {text: 'Right Tooltip', value: 'right_tooltip'},
                                {text: 'Bottom Tooltip', value: 'bottom_tooltip'}
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function( e ) 
                    {
                        editor.insertContent( '[tooltip class="' + e.data.listboxClassName + '" title="' + e.data.textboxtooltipName + '"]  html  [/tooltip]');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Now this line is the one who is responsible for displaying the SELECTED TEXT + the other attributes. Basically, I created an HTML Variable to catch the selected text however its not displaying on my code. Check out the code:

```
onsubmit: function( e ) 
{
    editor.insertContent( '[tooltip class="' + e.data.listboxClassName + '" title="' + e.data.textboxtooltipName + '"]  html  [/tooltip]'); 
}
```

Any idea what's up? How can I display the output of the getSelectionHtml function to the output of the anonymous function properly?

Comment: *"Basically, I created an HTML Variable to catch the selected text"* - i didn't get this part. Where? and why are you using `document.write(html);`? do you want to replace the entire document with the selected text?

Comment: Hi TJ I used html variable to get the Selected text on the window and then output it along with the other attributes on the anonymous function.

Comment: If you meant the following code in the function: `editor.insertContent( '[tooltip class="' + e.data.listboxClassName + '" title="' + e.data.textboxtooltipName + '"]  html  [/tooltip]');` there `html` is a string, not a variable. even if it is, you can't access it in an IIFE  unless it's global.

Comment: Can you fix the code for me? So that I can also check what you mean? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getSelectionHtml()` function gets the text selected on a page, but I think you want the text selected in the tinymce editor.

Try:

```
editor.insertContent(
    '[tooltip class="' + e.data.listboxClassName
    + '" title="' + e.data.textboxtooltipName + '"]'
    + editor.selection.getContent()
    + '[/tooltip]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
  html = ""; // removed var so that it can be accessed globally.
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
            container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
        }
        html = container.innerHTML;
    }
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
    if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
        html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
  }
 //document.write(html); this will rewrite the document - don't do this!
}
```

and in the anonnymous function:

```
onsubmit: function( e ) 
{
   getSelectionHtml(); // get selected the text
   if(html) // check whether text is selected
       editor.insertContent( '[tooltip class="' + e.data.listboxClassName + '" title="' + e.data.textboxtooltipName + '"]'+  html+'  [/tooltip]'); // html now reffers to the global variable
}
```

Comment: stil not getting the selected/highlighted HTML or TEXT. It's not displaying anything at all.

Comment: Check for errors in console: if nothing is there, replace `//document.write(html);` with `alert(html)` or `console.log(html)`, see if the function actually gets the text or not. check the flow one by one. this is called debugging. we can't help you with it unless we have the full code or a demo. Above are the fixes i saw regarding shared code. good luck.

Comment: It's not getting the Html at all TJ

Comment: @SamNorton then that's another problem. You should've checked whether that function is working or not before asking something like [Display function output within an anonymous function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25355578/2333214). Your question should've been [How to get selected text usining js](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+selected+text+using+js&oq=how+to+get+selected+text+using+js&aqs=chrome..69i57.7677j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) instead, which is of course a duplicate. Check the source of that code and do some research.